# Почему функция isset() считает, что элементы массива $_POST установлены, хотя это не так?

Tags: php, form

Есть два файла: form.html и cookie_set.php

form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="entry" action="cookie_set.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Вводите только цифры и буквы</legend>
        Имя: <input type="text" name="user">
        Пароль: <input type="password" name="pass">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

cookie_set.php

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST["user"])) echo "да<br>";
 if (isset($_POST["pass"])) echo "да<br>";
?>
```

Я не ввожу ни один элемент формы, нажимаю отправить и выводится 2 раза "да". по сути $_POST["user"] и $_POST["pass"] должны быть не установлены если в них не ввести значения, но функция isset() считает по-другому. Почему?

Но есть скрипт, в котором если не выбрать вариант ответа, isset() скажет, что элемент массива $_POST не установлен. Ниже приведены два файла
Еще два файла:
form2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="action2.php" method ="POST">
     <fieldset>
      <legend>Каким языком программирования является PHP?</legend>
      Структурным
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="structure"><br>
      Процедурным
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="procedure"><br>
      Объектно-ориентированным
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="OOP"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
     </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

action2.php

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
     $answer = $_POST['type'];
 }
 else {
     $answer = NULL;
 }
 echo "answer = $answer<br>";
 if ($answer != NULL) {
     if ($answer == "OOP") echo "Правильно!<br>";
     else echo "Неправильно!<br>";
 }
 else {
     echo "Вы не выбрали вариант.<br>";
 }
```

Comment: `action="cookie_set.php"` и код `doc.php`?

Comment: Я ошибся в указании файла php в вопросе. Сценарий называется cookie_set.php

Comment: @РустамГимранов исправил

Comment: Проверяйте if( empty ($_POST['user"]))

Comment: @axmed2004 спасибо, но я хочу разобраться почему не работает с isset()

Comment: @axmed2004 если программа работает не так, как ожидается, то я видимо что-то неправильно понял

Comment: На php давно не кодил, но помню если в поле ничего не вводить то empty даст true

Comment: Потому что они есть в форме и соответственно в запросе, хоть и пустые.

Comment: Пустая строка — это вполне конкретное значение, которое отличается от отсутствия значения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом случае при отправке пустой формы `var_dump($_POST);` выведет:

```
array(2) {
  ["user"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["pass"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Как видите `["user"] = ""` - пустая строка.

Функция `isset` возвращает **TRUE**, если переменная определена и ее значение отлично от **NULL**. В вашем случае, она равна пустой строке.

Функция `empty` - проверяет, пуста ли переменная. Переменная считается пустой, если она не существует или её значение равно:

1. *""* (пустая строка)
2. *0* (целое число)
3. *0.0* (число с плавающей точкой)
4. *"0"* (строка)
5. **NULL**
6. **FALSE**
7. *array()* (пустой массив)

---

Во втором случае: `checkbox` и `radio`, если они не выбраны, то они не передаются на сервер, и следовательно этих переменных нет в глобальном массиве $_POST. То же справедливо и для поля ввода типа `file` и наличие переменной в $_FILES.

Именно поэтому чаще всего с помощью `empty` проверяют на наличие и не пустоту.

```
if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
  ...
}
```

`empty` не генерирует предупреждение, если переменная не существует. Это значит, что `empty` фактически является точным эквивалентом конструкции

```
!isset($var) || $var == false
```

Comment: Спасибо)) Но я не понимаю почему тогда для input type="radio", isset() будет считать, что $_POST["..."] не существует. Я сейчас добавлю еще небольшой листинг в вопрос

Comment: Рустам Гимранов,  добавил