# Как проверить url на изображение?

Tags: php

У меня есть база данных.
Один из столбцов в ней `image`. В нём указан url изображения, но данные могут быть некорректными.

Как мне проверить элемент массива на картинку?

На пустоту и `null` проверяю так:

```
<?
$a="../img/animal.png";
if ((ltrim($result['image'], ' ') === '')||$result['image']==''||$result['image']==NULL){
$result['image']=$a;
}
 ?>
```

Comment: выполнить запрос по url и проверить что возвращается

Answer (score -3):

Допустим есть картинка в урл я её парсю;

```
$url = "https://celebniymir.ru/images/product/s/452e1eaa.jpg";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$page = curl_exec($curl);


$file='text0001.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $page);
```

Получаю кодированный текст абракадабра,
затем делаю ссылку битой 452e1eaa.jpg  добовляю 1 к 452e1eaa.jpg 
выходит так:

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: За что минус? ))

Comment: Вы вообще ничего не объяснили нормально. За это и минус.

Comment: @Bloom, автору нужно что-то на подобии [empty](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/980261/256824) плюс предварительный `trim`, чтобы переписать страшную проверку на `null`. И, вероятно, `file_exists`: изложено не понятно.

Comment: null  там никогда не будет, походу, условие ставить  по его изоображениям где он их берёт отпарсить все возможнные вариации и пробывать с ними работать

Comment: автору нужно проверить mime-тип контента на то, что он является изображением(image/*). Ваш ответ вообще непонятно о чём.

Comment: @vp_arth  чтоб сделать проверку файл предварительно нужно закачивать или на ходу проверяется? echo mime_content_type('php.gif') . "\n";